How to change testsuite name property in JUnit xml?
I'm using dotnet test with the junit logger option to run tests. The tests are compiled into a binary before they are run and the name of the binary is used as the testsuite name in the JUnit XML file. Example - E2ETests.dll
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="E2ETests.dll" tests="5" skipped="1" failures="2" errors="0" time="76.0077336" timestamp="2024-04-11T16:31:15" hostname="hostname" id="0" package="E2ETests.dll">

I would like to change the name of the testsuite in the XML file without modifying the binary to something like Automated_E2E_Tests. Is there an existing method or plan to allow changing the testsuite name that can be provided to dotnet test --logger:junit option?
So far, I have tried looking at the dotnet test command but found nothing suitable that helps.
I have also looked at the attributes list and couldn't find a way to override the .dll testsuite name.
